# How to add imageview to fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

There are tons of questions like this, but they all address adding a view in `onCreateView()` before returning the root layout. I want to add a view in the middle of code execution, in `onClick()`

---

**Note this is a fragment, which is why I can't update the UI without `onCreateView()`:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:

            //RelativeLayout Setup
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            //ImageView Setup
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

            //setting image resource
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lit);

            //setting image position
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button);

            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            //adding view to layout
            relativeLayout.addView(imageView);


            break;
    }
}
```

Here I get an instance of the layout and modify it. However, I cannot apply this modified fragment layout back into the application UI. How can I update the app interface after fragment UI modification?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A `Fragment`'s `View` is just like any other `View`. Whatever `View`s you're creating dynamically just need to be added to an on-screen `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks Mike, but even when I save an instance of `ViewGroup container`, and call `container.addView(relativeLayout)`, it doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean the `container` passed into `onCreateView()`, you probably don't want to use that. That's the `ViewGroup` in the `Activity` that's holding your `Fragment`'s whole `View`. You'll want to use a `ViewGroup` - e.g., a `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc. - that's in the layout you're inflating in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. But I'm already doing that in the code from my question, right? I add it to the Relative Layout, which is the root of my fragment...right?

Comment: No, you're creating a completely new `RelativeLayout` there. That's not the one that is created in `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

1. In my fragment's view xml, have a ViewGroup called `R.id.container` to hold your ImageViews.  In `onCreateView`, save a reference to this container.
2. Have a separate xml containing just the ImageView.  This way, you don't have to do any programmatic layout.

Then in your `onClick`, or wherever you need to add the ImageView:

```
ImageView newView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity).inflate(R.layout.image.xml);
mImageContainer.addView(newView);
// Ta da!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just created a view, but **haven't add to fragment's layout yet**.

Method `onCreateView()` will return the container of this fragment, save this instance (ex: `ViewGroup container`)

And when you create a view, like your RelativeLayout in `onClick()`, add it to container and your UI will be update.

`container.addView(relativeLayout);`

Example:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // i did this to see what see how button displays
        getView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // I create a new button and add it to the fragment's layout.
                Button button = new Button(getActivity());
                ((LinearLayout)getView()).addView(button);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

The layout `example_fragment` is simply a LinearLayout

Comment: The add method doesn't exist for some reason though? I get `cannot resolve  method add(android.widget.RelativeLayout)` when I try to add it to the saved container. What should I do?

Comment: Even trying `container.addView` doesn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: You can create a field when inflate the fragment's layout. Then use it as container anywhere of your code. Or call `getView()` to retrieve the view created by `onCreateView()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused on what you mean. So I save an instance of the `ViewGroup container`. But why do I need `getView()`? And how should I add the view to my fragment?

Comment: yes, you saved the View container instance. Then to add a view into the container. call `container.add(view)`

Comment: But the `add(View v)` method doesn't exist, there is only `addView(View child)`. However, even when I tried doing `container.addView(relativeLayout)`, nothing happened...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114688/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-alex-hong).